# Would it be valid to compare two slightly different questions using frequency?

Tags: survey, validation, social-science

I administered a questionnaire, and one of the questions asked:  Indicate all of the activities you did while on your most recent trip (please select all that apply). There are 20 or so options to choose from.  I copied this question from a questionnaire asked by a government organization however I excluded some of the activities the government listed and combined other activities to keep my question fairly short.  Also, my participant sample is much smaller than that of the government questionnaire.

So, now I am wondering if I can compare my answers with those of the governmental organization.  My research is exploratory and qualitative in nature, therefore I am not trying to verify anything, I just want to see if patterns might exist.

Comment: You may use one-sample t-test to test if there is any significant difference.

Comment: The questions are in the form of a likert scale so i think i would have to use friedman's test.   The problem though, is that my questions are not exactly the same as the gov't questions, so i don't know if i could pair the questions 1 to 1 and do the test 20 times, and know with certainty that the comparison would be valid. Or am I unclear as to how these tests are applied?